# What is the converted mana cost of land cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What is the converted mana cost (CMC) of land cards? Is it zero?

For example, if I have lands in the graveyard, would [Sun Titan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSun%20Titan%5d) be able to bring them to the battlefield?

Comment: I would just like to add that a very basic question does not make a question bad. Even if this rules knowledge is a thing that most players know there still may be players that are unaware and having a canonical answer here might still prove useful.

Comment: I'd like to add that people might forget such a rule; it happened to me that an opponent said "nope" when I said "azor's gateway trigger". Yes, a land exiled by gateway counts as a "0-CMC" card, which is indeed different than 1-,2-,3-... cmc cards.

Comment: As long as "Converted Mana Cost" and "Mana Cost" are different, and we have Modern staples featuring lands with converted mana costs (Azcanta) and cards with CMC but not a mana cost (Ancestral Recall), this actually isn't something I would necessarily classify under basic knowledge.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### It's 0<sup>†</sup>, so [Sun Titan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSun%20Titan%5d) can bring them back.

This is also noted in the rulings below the card in Gatherer:

> If a card in your graveyard has no mana symbols in its upper right corner (because it’s a land card, for example), its converted mana cost is 0.

<sup>†</sup>: with the exception of transformed lands, as noted in [@NeilMeyer's answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/48488/12315). This situation doesn't happen in the graveyard, though.

Answer (score 12):

## One notable exception.

Certain double-faced cards from Ixalan block become lands when they are transformed. These lands have the CMC of their front face which is often not equal to 0.

[Adanto, the First Fort](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAdanto%2c%20the%20First%20Fort%5d), the transformed side of [Legion's Landing](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLegion%27s%5d%2b%5bLanding%5d) for instance, has a CMC of 1.

> 711.4b While a double-faced permanent’s back face is up, it has only the characteristics of its back face. However, its converted mana cost
>   is calculated using the mana cost of its front face. If a permanent is
>   copying the back face of a double-faced card (even if the card
>   representing that copy is itself a double-faced card), the converted
>   mana cost of that permanent is 0.

Answer (score 10):

### The converted mana cost of a land card is 0

> 202.3a: The converted mana cost of an object with no mana cost is 0, unless that object is the back face of a double-faced permanent or is a melded permanent.

So yes, Sun Titan's triggered ability could bring a land to the battlefield.